# how to make "strike out" rotate with the rest of the figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a figure which I generated using the code below. Basically, when I use  `[rotate=45]` option, I would like to ensure that the strike out symbol is rotated as well.

Also, related to this figure, how can I make it connect 2 nodes? (such that its size automatically fits the space between)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
    \draw (-0.5,0)-- ++(+0.5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \draw ++(-0.5,0.15) -- ++(+0.5,0);
    \draw (-0.15,-0.15)-- (0,0);
    \draw ++(0,0.15)--+(-0.15,+0.15);
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (+0.075,+0.075) .. (0,0.15);
    \coordinate (A) at (-0.5,0.15);
    \node [strike out,draw,anchor=text] (X) at ++($ (A)!.5!(B) $) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A screenshot of the result:

[image]

As As you might observe, the striking out symbol remains as is.

---

Here is a before and after, for comparison:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the output you get would help people immediately understand the issue you're having.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45,transform shape]...\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks very much, indeed. Could you please help me with the other issue as well? I would like to make this figure as a 'connector' between two nodes. Cheers

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, adding the `transform shape` option to the `tikzpicture` environment solves the rotation issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45,transform shape]
    \draw (-0.5,0)-- ++(+0.5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \draw ++(-0.5,0.15) -- ++(+0.5,0);
    \draw (-0.15,-0.15)-- (0,0);
    \draw ++(0,0.15)--+(-0.15,+0.15);
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (+0.075,+0.075) .. (0,0.15);
    \coordinate (A) at (-0.5,0.15);
    \node [strike out,draw,anchor=text] (X) at ++($ (A)!.5!(B) $) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks indeed, accepted with great pleasure! Just a minor question, how can I ensure that a figure I make in Tikz (say the one above) lies between two specific nodes, please? (so that its size is automatically adjusted)

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Thanks you very much for accepting the answer! Regarding the other issue, I see that you've already opened a new question for this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195355/how-to-connect-nodes-with-a-figure-created-in-tikz so perhaps someone will provide an answer there (I might have a look at it later).