# how to connect nodes with a figure created in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created a sort of 'implies' sign (as well as a 'not implies' sign). How can I make them *both* connect two nodes?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45, transform shape]
    \draw (-0.5,0)-- ++(+0.5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \draw ++(-0.5,0.15) -- ++(+0.5,0);
    \draw (-0.15,-0.15)-- (0,0);
    \draw ++(0,0.15)--+(-0.15,+0.15);
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (+0.075,+0.075) .. (0,0.15);
    \coordinate (A) at (-0.5,0.15);
    \node [strike out,draw,anchor=text] (X) at ++($ (A)!.5!(B) $) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect a figure could be 'saved' in a kind of macro but I am not sure

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/ and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115752/

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for the extremely useful reference. It would be also great to have a solution in my specific case too. Cheers!

Comment: Voted unclear: you asked for a solution for your specific case, but I can't even tell exactly what you want and you also didn't provide the full code needed to produce your diagram. (How is `strike out` defined, for instance?)